# how to send a failure response from django to ajax

Tags: ajax, django

I have this Ajax request:

```
    $.ajax({
            url: "my_url",
            headers: {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
            type: "post",
            data:{x:1
                 },
            success: function(response, textStatus, xhr) {
                alert(response + textStatus + xhr);

            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status + ' Error: ' + thrownError);
            }
          });

}
```

On the Django side, I sometimes want to propagate errors.
If I raise an exception, it will propagate as a 500 response INTERNAL ERROR.
But I want to display an error message.
So I tried

```
return HttpResponse("Bad permissions", status=500)
```

But I'm not able to capture the custom error message.
Any ideas?

---

For those of you who want to know what worked:

### Javascript in template

```
function send(){
    $.ajax({
            url: "/get_pens/",
            headers: {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
            type: "post",
            data:{x:1
                 },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response, textStatus, xhr) {
                alert('Success: ' + response + textStatus + xhr);

            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status + ' Error: ' + xhr.responseJSON['err']);
            }
          });
}
```

### views.py

```
def get_pens(request):
    pens = []
    response = HttpResponse(json.dumps({'pens': pens, 'err': 'some custom error message'}), 
        content_type='application/json')
    response.status_code = 400
    return response
```

Comment: Can't you just send a json like `{'status': 'success'}` or `{'status': 'the custom error message'}` and display the error message when `status` is not `success`?

Comment: 500 isn't really appropriate here. This is either a bad request (400) or in the specific case of invalid permissions, 403. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseBadRequest)

Comment: Are you _catching_ the exception that's happening? It will never get to your `HttpResponse` or whatever you're using unless you do that.

Comment: I can just send a response for example a json response and check whether there is an error key but it sounds like a wrong approach. I think the correct way should involve using the response status but I don't know how.

Comment: `alert(....)`works. But did you try to add the message to a div `$('#some-id').html(xhr.responseJSON['err'])` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way you can approach this is as following,

You have proper try exception blocks around the code around the block which are prone to raise exceptions. There are lot many Exception subclasses which can cover the type of the exception being raised for eg. Model.DoesNotExist. In those exception blocks, you simply create appropriate HttpResponse and send it back. Lets take an example here.

```
class DemoView(View):
    def post(self, request, oid, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        object = Model.objects.get(id=oid)
    except Model.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponseNotFound('error message')
```

This way your error block is executed in your ajax function. You might consider it as a way to go and seems a right approach to me.

**Update:**
Based on the comment you(OP) made below, you can have a response created in following fashion

```
def bad_request(message):
    response = HttpResponse(json.dumps({'message': message}), 
        content_type='application/json')
    response.status_code = 400
    return response
```

When you want to return status 400, you simply do,

```
return bad_request(message='This is a bad request')
```

So following this, in your ajax error function, you can use following to get that message,

```
xhr.responseJSON.message
```

Comment: I tried it, but on the ajax side I still do not receive the custom error message.

Comment: I have updated my answer in response to your comment.

Comment: I did not try it with the status_code but tried it by setting the status in the constructor as in my original post above and I tell you that for some weird reason, on the ajax side it does not enter the error block. Instead, it still enters the success block.

Comment: @RajeshYogeshwar If the status_code is added, then alerting the message works, but showing the message in a div like `$('#some-id').html(xhr.responseJSON.message)` doesn't.

Comment: @Boky Is should not be any be different. Because `xhr.responseJSON.message` basically returns a string and `('#some-id').html(xhr.responseJSON.message)` is what it should be. Can you share your snippet, if possible?

Answer (score 1):

Here a version for Django 3.0 and Python 3.0. First define a subclass of `JsonResponse`:

```py
class FailedJsonResponse(JsonResponse):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__(data)
        self.status_code = 400
```

The use it in your own code:

```py
return FailedJsonResponse({"e": "Error message"})
```